# Spring Boot JMS with SQS is consuming too much CPU

Tags: spring-boot, jms, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I have a spring boot application and within that application I have 6 @JmsListener. The configuration of JmsListenerContainerFactory is

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
  SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory) {
    final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory
    = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(10);
    factory.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    factory.setErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler());
return factory;
}
```

The max heap memory is configured to be 2GB and usually the application is running at 1GB. But the CPU usage is going upto 100%. I am using SQS and couldn't understand why the CPU usage is going to 100%.
I am sharing my thread dump [here](https://pastebin.com/bKPT4Wps). Please help me to understand the issue.

Comment: A thread dump is generally not useful to analyze such situations; it's just a snapshot in time; you need to profile the application (e.g. YourKit) to see where the time is being spent.

Comment: Does setting `receiveTimeout` to a value of 100000 change your behavior?

Comment: Yeah I see some improvement by setting receiveTimeout

Comment: I see many Prefetch threads also but I have set it to 0, don't know the behaviour of aws messaging library